# Is it possible to compress/change the DPI of a PDF page in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a PDF with a huge page size.  I'm looking to scale down the page to A4 size (in essence - I need to reduce the DPI), and along the way reduce the size of the PDF in KB.
Is there away to do this with PDFBox? Other open source libraries in Java?

Comment: Changing the page size is not going to have any effect. What you need to do is remove the objects that take the most space. That may include things like removing metadata, compressing uncompressed streams, downsampling any images in the file, changing compression of images to something like JPEG compression and so on.

Comment: Can you share the PDF? There are many reasons that a PDF is bigger than you expect. Is your question about one PDF, or a family of such files?

Comment: The question is about one specific PDF which is created by one of our customers.  We use pdf.js to display the PDF in a browser.  The problem is that it doesn't display on iPads and iPhones, because the resolution of the PDF is too high.  I'm trying to find a way to scale down the pages programatically to A4 size, without losing any of the content.

Comment: If this is about one specific PDF, then "print" it to a PDF, and see if it gets smaller. If this doesn't help, try printing programmatically from PDFBox into a PDF but use the dpi parameter (see in the examples subdirectory), this way you can force e.g. 300 dpi or less.

Comment: Once more, page size of a PDF _is not_ related to the size of the file. Scaling a page isn't going to change the size of the PDF therefor. You need to modify the PDF content, specifically the content of any resources that are too big.